# Documenting tags in between paragraphs in Pythons Epydoc

Tags: python, tags, documentation, epydoc

I'm writing documentation for methods in python that is supposed to be available for end users to read through. I'm using Epydoc field tags to document the argument based on requirements given to me, and am trying to put the parameter description in between the description of the method and the examples of using the method as such:

```
"""
A description of what this utility does.


@param utilityArguments: Description of arguments
@type utilityArguments: String


A list of examples:

example1

example2

example3

"""
```

Unfortunately I have not had any success in finding a way to exclude the examples from the type tag, and they get added to it instead of being separate. I'm trying to not move the parameters to the end of the argument because we feel this looks neater; is there any way to terminate a tag for documentation and exclude any following text from it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to be the bearer of bad news, but the [Epydoc documentation](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/epytext.html) specifically disallows this behavior:

> Fields must be placed at the end of the docstring, after the description of the object. Fields may be included in any order.

Since fields are all `@param` and `@return` markups, that means that all things after a field will be considered a part of that field (unless it is another field).